# Can php create a xspf file the same way as it writes xml?

Tags: php, xml, xspf

I know you can create an xml file with php

```
$doc->save("write.xml")
```

but is it possible to write to another file type, like .[xspf](http://www.xspf.org/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just change the file name.

An xspf file is just XML with a different filename extension.

Comment: Great!  I was hoping that was the answer.. i just didnt want to dive in without being certain.  I will accept when it lets me.

Comment: @Zac, no problem, but next time, dive in.  You'll learn much faster that way.  No need to wait... you won't break anything by experimenting.  Also, thanks for the props on the corn hat.  It's actually a WiFi enabled corn hat with a wireless repeater inside.  :-D